# query to extract values from xml

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have xml stored in the db ,  want to extract certain parts from that like the one after text, the complete query .
Into the xml I have many queries and want then to be extracted as well.
Do we have some method to do it .

eg : extract the query not the value , the xml is embedded into the db and has format like below.
text="query1"
text="query2"
text="query3"

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL or Oracle? Oracles owns both, but they are still quite different :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to go do some research on Oracle XMLTYPE usage, but here is a quick function from a package I am currently working on that shows the use of .existsnode to validate that a node is there, and .extract to pull the information

```
FUNCTION parse_order_by_xml (p_xml_document IN XMLTYPE) RETURN varchar2
   IS
        /*** xml document structure *** start
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <OrderByClause>
            <OrderBy>
                <ColumnName>ELECTOR_ID</ColumnName>
                <Order>Asc</Order>
            </OrderBy>
            <OrderBy>
                <ColumnName>CREATED_TS</ColumnName>
                <Order>Desc</Order>
            </OrderBy>
        </OrderByClause>
        *** xml document structure *** end ***/
        l_order_by_string varchar2(3000) := 'ORDER BY ';
        l_index number;
   BEGIN
        l_index := 1;
        WHILE (p_xml_document.existsnode('/OrderByClause/OrderBy[' || to_char(l_index) || ']') = 1) LOOP
            l_order_by_string :=        l_order_by_string
                                    ||  p_xml_document.extract('/OrderByClause/OrderBy[' || to_char(l_index) || ']/ColumnName/text()').getStringVal()
                                    ||  ' '
                                    ||  p_xml_document.extract('/OrderByClause/OrderBy[' || to_char(l_index) || ']/Order/text()').getStringVal()
                                    ||  ',';
            l_index := l_index + 1;
        END LOOP;

        l_order_by_string := REGEXP_REPLACE(l_order_by_string, ',$');

        RETURN l_order_by_string;
   END parse_order_by_xml;
```